# Google Spreadsheet: Dividing unique count result by two

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I'm using the following formula:

```
=ArrayFormula(QUERY(C3:C37&{"",""},"select Col1, count(Col2) where Col1 != '' group by Col1 label count(Col2) 'Count'",1))
```

On Google Sheets to return the unique values within a range of cells on a new column and number of occurrences for each unique value on a column to its right.

I would now like to divide the values returned by 2 and I tried several solutions but they don't seem to work, would you be able to help me out?

Thank you!

Comment: `count(Col2)/2`

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, sadly it doesn't work, even if I try to enclose it in brackets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change the label part as well as the select part

```
=ArrayFormula(QUERY(C4:C37&{"",""},"select Col1, count(Col2)/2 where Col1 != '' group by Col1 label count(Col2)/2 'Count'",1))
```